# SailsJS - Waterline - Many to Many Database Table

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I've joined an existing project where we use SailsJS and Waterline for our ORM.
I've noticed the following database table : category_items__item_categories but I don't see any model for it.

Here's the actual models:

**Item.JS**

```
Item.JS
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        description: {
            type: 'string',
            allowNull: true
        },
        categories: {
            collection: 'category',
            via: 'items',
        },
    }
}
```

**Category.JS**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        description: {
            type: 'string',
            allowNull: true
        },
        items: {
            collection: 'item',
            via: 'categories',
        },
    }
}
```

Does SailsJS generate tables at all? does it generate many to many tables?
If not , how does it represent many to many relationship in the data store (in this case PostgreSQL database)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sails does generate its own join tables, if you don't provide your own "through" model. See this answer to see how to create your own "through" model: [SailsJS - Waterline - add column to many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006210/sailsjs-waterline-add-column-to-many-to-many-relationship/73014656#73014656)

Comment: So the above table (category_items__item_categories) will be automatically generated when I create the first model?

In general , are the tables are created  when you create the first model / entry?